# mysql nested select multiple parameters

Tags: mysql

Guessing/hoping this is easy and it's a mysql newb issue.

Single client table with text fields for year, month, day (no timestamp or date fields ouch). Looking to select dates after day. Can figure ways around easily but what's the mysql way of doing this? **Not working** pseudo code

```
SELECT * FROM `venuedates` 
WHERE `year`='2017' AND `month` <> 'January' AND (IF `month`='February' AND day > 24)
```

So none from Jan and only after certain day in Feb. Thanks for any info.

Comment: StackOverFlow is for asking questions about actual code.  Not pseudo code.

Comment: Question has been answered. What was written was broken actual code to describe the problem and answered bellow. So should I edit question to replace "pseudo" with "broken"?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select *
from `venuedates`
where `year` = '2017'
    and `month` <> 'January'
    and (
        `month` <> 'February'
        or (
            `month` = 'February'
            and day > 24
            )
        )
```

This asserts that

- year is 2017
- month must not be January
- if month is February then day should be greater than 24
- if not February, any day

You will be better off storing day, month, year information as one single column of DATE datatype.

If it was a date column, it would be trivial like:

```
select *
from `venuedates`
where date between '2017-02-25' and '2017-12-31'
```

Comment: Yeah! That works thanks!

Comment: @openquestions [Glad I could help.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `venuedates` 
WHERE `year`='2017' AND `month` <> 'January' AND (`month`<>'February' OR day > 24)
```

Comment: .. doh! That works thanks man! I was trying stuff like this for a while but thestupidisstrong today.

Comment: you can mark it as correct if it was helpful.

Comment: @openquestions Have fun with this solution, when you need records after 24th of June.

Comment: Yours and GurV both work. Looking around for how to mark correct.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel hmmm not testing that as the existing table is very sparse. Are you saying this will break. I'm going to dummy up a test later - as tempting as it is to add multiple entries to client table ... no I'll dummy it later.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel whats the problem for record after 24th of june?

Comment: @openquestions option for 'correct' is just below the upvote option.

Comment: @TanujYadav Just write the same query for June and tell me that you don't see any "problem".

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Actually i am busy right now. So can u plz explain?

Comment: @TanujYadav You would need to exclude all months before June. I would like to see how you will do that without hard coding all those months.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel but i think the question doesnt asks to exclude all the months before feb/june?

Comment: "Looking to select dates **after day**"

Comment: @PaulSpiegel "none from Jan and only after certain day in Feb". I think we understood the question differently. I know what you are trying to say.

Comment: Ok.. The question is ambiguous. If this is going to be a one-time-query, then everything is fine :-)

Comment: No this is a one time issue. Excluded months would have to be hard coded. I'm completely amateur with mysql but my instinct is to parse all entries and store as date or timestamp, I just don't know their codebase well enough to be sure I won't breaking something on entry/edit and the client is too cheap to fix anything for long term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM `venuedates` 
WHERE `year`='2017' 
AND (`month` <> 'February' OR (`month`='February' AND day > 24)) 
AND `month` <> 'January'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine `STR_TO_DATE()` and `CONCAT_WS()` to construct a valid date. Then you can use a simple comparison.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `venuedates` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ', `year`, `month`, `day`), '%Y %M %d') > '2017-02-24'
```

But you better store your dates as `DATE` type.

Comment: This solution can't make use of indexes and will suffer from performance issues on a decent sized table.

Comment: @GurV Please show me a solution which can use an index.